# Can't login with python requests, even after making a get request first, and setting headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get data from a page. I've tried to read the posts of other people who had the same problem, Making a get request first to get cookies, setting headers, none of it works. When I examine the output of `print(soup.title.get_text())` I still end up getting "Log In" as the title returned. The `login_data` has the same key names as the HTML `<input>` elements, e.g `<input name=ctl00$cphMain$logIn$UserName ...>` for username and `<input name=ctl00$cphMain$logIn$Password ...>` for password. Not sure what to do next. I can't use selenium, as I have to execute this script on an EC2 instance that's running a splunk server.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "****"
login_URL = "https://erecruit.elwoodstaffing.com/Login.aspx"
login_data = {
"ctl00$cphMain$logIn$UserName": "****",
"ctl00$cphMain$logIn$Password": "****"
} 



with requests.Session() as session:
    z = session.get(login_URL) 
    session.headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
}
    post = session.post(login_URL, data=login_data)
    response = session.get(link) 
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print(soup.title.get_text())
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending all the data and headers needed? You can use your browser's developer tools to see all the data your browser sends normally in order to replicate it properly.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure of your exact circumstances but if you use something like headless Chrome/Chromium that doesn't need a display you can usually use Selenium on a headless server like an EC2 instance. If you aren't constrained to Python and are comfortable with JavaScript you could also use [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) which is a Node library for controlling headless Chrome/Chromium that comes with its own version of Chromium so you don't have to worry about dependencies as much.

Comment: try also adding your cookies

Comment: To emphasize what @ftm said: There are **several** `<input>` elements in that form besides the username and password.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar, the `Session` object should keep track of the cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer.

You can basically just go to the network tab using chrome, and then copy requests as a cURL statement. Then, just use a website or tool to convert the cURL statement to its programming language equivalent (Python, node, java, and so forth).